# Partitioning of hard disk using GParted in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, gparted

I was going through my hard disk partitioning and found two partitions of which I have no idea about,  `/dev/sda8` and `/dev/sda9`.
What do these partitions actually represent, and is it OK to delete them?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

GParted only recognizes the file systems outlined on the [GParted Features page](https://gparted.org/features.php).

You might try the following command in a terminal window to learn what type of file system might be installed in the unknown partitions:

```
sudo blkid
```

Search the output for the partitions you are curious about.  For example in your case:

```
sudo blkid | egrep "sda8|sda9"
```